# "Where" as a relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

I came across this sentence when reading a blog:

> "My aspiration is to have a fulfilling life where, when i am 60 years old, i can look back and feel happy about the richness of it all."

It seems to me *where* is used as a relative pronoun in the sentence, and probably due to my poor Googling skills, I couldn't find any detailed explanations on the usage of *where* as a relative pronoun. Could anyone give me some examples?

Comment: "Where" is a relative word here. It's not a pronoun -- trad grammar classifies it as an adverb, but modern grammar takes it as a preposition. It is most often used as an adjunct of place, as in "I know a perfect place [where we can relax]". It can also be used with head nouns that don't suggest a location, as in your example.

Comment: @BillJ I am not in the position to argue with you Bill, but I think in traditional Grammar it's called subordinate conjunction.

Comment: @Cardinal  It's usually called a 'relative adverb' : [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Where" is used to introduce **a relative clause that describes a certain situation** (so you are, in a way, "in" a situation, though not in a physical, literal *place*).

Examples:

> — ["I have this condition where my ovaries don't work anymore and I'm not that interested in sex"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=doJlNj4h70EC&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=%22i+have+this+condition+where%22&source=bl&ots=M7yXzVvDQV&sig=WcRTl0D9w3epDC0qnf4iXECSl64&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR9a_9yqDZAhVFkiwKHWG-B5wQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22i%20have%20this%20condition%20where%22&f=false)
>
> — ["Mental health plays a big role in this feeling where you get stuck thinking ‘I don’t think this is for me,’..."](https://www.uclahealth.org/study-shows-stigma-around-mental-health-on-campus-correlates-with-students-not-seeking-treatment)

This might have something to do with how, in English, an emotional state or a situation can be described as a "place" from which one is coming.

Examples:

> — She decided to **come from a place of love** when dealing with herself and everyone else. ([source](http://www.queenofyourownlife.com/blog/coming-from-a-place-of-love))
>
> — Whenever I work with clients, my aim is to get them to **a place of acceptance** – or neutrality – around their body.] ([source](https://sarahvance.com/body-acceptance-part-1/))
>
> — This was a hard period in my life, but I'm **in a better place** now. (I feel better, more confident, etc.)

Comment: So, could I also use "in which" to replace "where? "My aspiration is to have a fulfilling life in which when i am 60 years old, i can look back and feel happy about the richness of it all"

Comment: @TomLee Yes, exactly. You can replace it by "in which"; it will be correct. It's just that "where" often gives the sentence a better "flow".